# Flutter - How to convert String to map<int,int>

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to convert a simple string to map that witch crated by myMap.toString()

```
My array is like this "{ 0:0 , 1:1 , 9:25 , 15:12352}"
```

I have the code below

```
Map<int, int> myMap= {};
myMap[0]=0;
myMap[1]=1;
JJ.localStorage!.setString("myMap",myMap.toString());
String? tempStr = JJ.localStorage?.getString("myMap");
final temp2 = jsonDecode(tempStr!);
print("----------------------------$temp2[0]------------------------------");
```

I see this error

```
Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
Blockquote
```

Comment: It sounds to me that your string is not `'{ 0:0 , 1:1 , 9:25 , 15:12352}'` and instead has a string `'Blockquote'` embedded in it.